# Entity Framework throws "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mariadb, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this exception:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: p2072

This is when `SaveChanges` is called after adding the entities to the `DbContext`.

The strange thing is that it says **"Key: p2072"**, but it doesn't match any key of my entity.

The primary key is configured as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestEntity>().HasKey(e => new { e.Nif, e.Especialidad, e.Cuerpo });
```

where:

- Nif is `string`
- Especialidad is `int`
- Cuerpo is `Enum`

You can see the complete definition of the entity. It's as follows:

```
public class RequestEntity
{
    public string Nif { get; set; }
    public Provincias Provincias { get; set; }
    public Cuerpo Cuerpo { get; set; }
    public int Especialidad { get; set; }
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public Idiomas Idiomas { get; set; }
    public int Orden { get; set; }
}
```

**Provicias, Cuerpo, Idiomas and Estado are Enums**. Notice that there aren't any relationships to other entities, only primitive types.

I'm having a hard time debugging this, because there are +23,000 entities to be added and it seems that there aren't any duplicates.

Moreover, the key that it's showing (p2072) has no sense. The only string in the key is  Nif, but there is no matching Nif.

### Edit

This is the stack trace:

> at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException(Object
>   key)    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key,
>   TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.CreateStoreCommand()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.MySqlBatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1
>   commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entries)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entriesToSave)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()    at
>   Plugin.Clm.Importer.Importer.SaveNewResults(ImportResult results)

### Edit 2

Just before the `SaveChanges`, I've put this line:

```
        var duplicates = requestEntities.GroupBy(e=>new{e.Nif, e.Especialidad, e.Cuerpo}).Select(x=>new{x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
            .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
            .ToList();
```

The funny thing is that `duplicates` has nothing (0 elements). What's going on?

Comment: In my experience "An Item with the same key has already been added" should be thrown during attach, not .SaveChanges(). However, it might be that they changed that in core. In order to debug, you could try splitting all entries into small chunks like 100 entries and debug like that, I highly suspect duplicates. To check easily, you can also check the expression entries.GroupBy(e=>new{e.Nif, e.Especialidad, e.Cuerpo}).Select(x=>new{x.Key, x.Count()});

Comment: Can we see the exception stack trace?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Please, look for the updated question.

Comment: @IvanStoev Please, look for the updated question, since I have added the stack trace.

Comment: From stack trace and EF Core source code, `p2072` seems to be a **db command parameter name**. Could be a bug the database provider (not sure which one are you using) or parameter count limit related. I think you should report this to EF Core issue tracker. You could try committing on batches, e.g. call `SaveChanges` after every let say 1000 added entities as a workaround or just to confirm that this is the case.

Comment: Most likely a bug in [MySQL EF Core Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/mysql/)

Comment: OK, I just found the problem. It's a bug. I'm using the Pomelo Mysql EF Provider. Updating to the latest version fixed the problem. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

It happens to be a bug in the Pomelo EF MySQL provider I'm using! Updating to the latest version solves the problem.